# Custom dialog gives exception for display the map v2 with supportfragment when 2 time is called?

Tags: android, dictionary, fragment, customdialog

i want to display the map v2 in custom dialog is also display the map but when i close the custom  dialog and once again i am called the custom dialog is gives error
here i put my code for that class

> Activity class

```
public class MainActivity extends  FragmentActivity {


     PopupWindow pw;
     GoogleMap map;
     final Context context = this;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

         DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
            getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);

          final int  screenheight = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
          final int   screenwidth = displaymetrics.widthPixels;

        Button button= (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // custom dialog
                final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);

                dialog.getWindow().setLayout((screenwidth*90)/100,(screenheight*90)/100);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.popupstellodetailpage);
                dialog.setTitle("Title...");

                map= ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                       .findFragmentById(R.id.popupmapview)).getMap(); 


                Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.buttoncancel);
                // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
                dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });

                dialog.show();


            }
        });

    }
```

> main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

> Popupstellodetail.xml

<

```
LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/popuplayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttoncancel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Cancel"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
             />

          <fragment
                    android:id="@+id/popupmapview"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />



</LinearLayout>
```

Logcat Error

```
04-17 13:09:06.391: E/AndroidRuntime(11978): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-17 13:09:06.391: E/AndroidRuntime(11978): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class fragment
04-17 13:09:06.391: E/AndroidRuntime(11978):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
04-17 13:09:06.391: E/AndroidRuntime(11978):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
04-17 13:09:06.391: E/AndroidRuntime(11978):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
04-17 13:09:06.391: E/AndroidRuntime(11978):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
04-17 13:09:06.391: E/AndroidRuntime(11978):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
04-17 13:09:06.391: E/AndroidRuntime(11978):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:306)
04-17 13:09:06.391: E/AndroidRuntime(11978):    at android.app.Dialog.setContentView(Dialog.java:467)
04-17 13:09:06.391: E/AndroidRuntime(11978):    at com.example.stiptis.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:58)
04-17 13:09:06.391: E/AndroidRuntime(11978):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4222)
04-17 13:09:06.391: E/AndroidRuntime(11978):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17273)
04-17 13:09:06.391: E/AndroidRuntime(11978):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
04-17 13:09:06.391: E/AndroidRuntime(11978):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-17 13:09:06.391: E/AndroidRuntime(11978):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-17 13:09:06.391: E/AndroidRuntime(11978):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4895)
04-17 13:09:06.391: E/AndroidRuntime(11978):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-17 13:09:06.391: E/AndroidRuntime(11978):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-17 13:09:06.391: E/AndroidRuntime(11978):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:994)
04-17 13:09:06.391: E/AndroidRuntime(11978):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:761)
04-17 13:09:06.391: E/AndroidRuntime(11978):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-17 13:09:06.391: E/AndroidRuntime(11978): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #16: Duplicate id 0x7f040008, tag null, or parent id 0x0 with another fragment for com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment
04-17 13:09:06.391: E/AndroidRuntime(11978):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:285)
04-17 13:09:06.391: E/AndroidRuntime(11978):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:676)
04-17 13:09:06.391: E/AndroidRuntime(11978):    ... 18 more
```

Comment: Instead of creating custom dialog just try creating the activity and set its layout properties to Theme.Dialog and try.. may that solve your problem.

Comment: not getting what you trying to say ?

Answer (score 0):

Look at line 1 of your xml says your logcat